# Windows PowerShell - Interact with Python script Remote PC

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I would like to write a PowerShell script which will execute a Python script on a remote PC. The script prompts the user to type 'Y' or 'N' to continue execution of it.

To log in remotely, I type

```
enter-pssession -ComputerName <Computer Name> -Credential <DOMAIN>\<username>
```

Then I type:

```
python ".\update_software.py"
```

The script prints out the text before the prompt, but instead of the prompt, I receive the following error message:

```
python.exe : Traceback (most recent call last):
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Traceback (most recent call last)::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

 File ".\update_software.py", line 19, in <module>
_runner.execute()
 File "C:\aimplatform2\aim\software_updater\run_update.py", line 76, in execute
 res = raw_input("> ")
 EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

If it helps, I am running Windows XP and remoting into a Windows XP machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to python documentation,

```
raw_input([prompt]) -> string

Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped.
If the user hits EOF (Unix: Ctl-D, Windows: Ctl-Z+Return), raise EOFError.
On Unix, GNU readline is used if enabled.  The prompt string, if given,
is printed without a trailing newline before reading.
```

So you must have pressed (or Powershell might have inserted that) CTRL+Z Enter in your raw_input function.

Comment: So is there any way to execute this script including the prompt or would removing the prompt solve my problems?

Comment: try to replace your raw_input and supply the required input as a command line argument to your update_software.py

Comment: I did that and the script was able to run. Thanks for your help